# Check Object? for empty

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to save a value of type `Object?` in the Provider state in Flutter, but I can't check if it's empty or not.

```
Object? _session = {};
Object? get session => _session;
set session(Object? newValue) {
  _session = newValue;
  notifyListeners();
}
```

Then in widget

```
AppStateContent content = Provider.of<AppStateContent>(context);
```

The `content.session.isEmpty` returns `The getter 'isEmpty' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.`

The `content.session != {}` doesn't return the `EmptyScreen()` widget when the session object isn't modified.

```
 content.session != {}
      ? const CurrentScreen()
      : const EmptyScreen(),
```

Comment: what does not work with `content.session.isEmpty` method?

Comment: Because the type that is being returned from the service that I use is an `Object?` and it won't allow `Map?` I used the solution from the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try leaving it in the null.

```
Object? _session;
Object? get session => _session;
set session(Object? newValue) {
  _session = newValue;
  notifyListeners();
}
```

```
content.session != null
      ? const CurrentScreen()
      : const EmptyScreen(),
```

Comment: Yeah ... this works. Thank you. I tried this I think, but didn't work. Now it's fine. Have to check once the session is populated. Can only do that from a device. Testing on emulator atm.